# Alamofire: how to handle and classify errors?

Tags: swift, alamofire

One example for Alamofire is given as:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
     .validate()
     .responseJSON { response in
         switch response.result {
         case .Success:
             print("Validation Successful")
         case .Failure(let error):
             print(error)
         }
     }
```

How can I handle errors like "network in down", "404", "server not found", to give informative excuses to the user for why their stuff isn't loading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get http status code and handler it like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, USERS_URL, headers: headers, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let data):
                if response.response!.statusCode == 200 {
                  //do things
                }else if response.response!.statusCode == 401 {
                    //do things
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
    }
```

Comment: Is there documentation of the `.Failure` cases? And does it include network down / server not reachable errors?

Comment: .Success is in case the request is success and .Failure means cant do the request! The http status is from the response from the server

Comment: @ChrisAllinson

You could look at the Alamofire documentation for more infos. 
https://alamofire.github.io/Alamofire/Enums/AFError.html

Here is another post which might be helpful. 
https://gist.github.com/perlguy99/f7f336b66ccb27fcc148b7d5bdbc9a3f